# How can I build an associative array recursively using keys from another array?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

Ok, so this is a bit tricky and I hit a wall.

What I have is an array of grouping options:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [9] => sum
            [10] => sum
            [11] => avg
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [9] => sum
            [10] => sum
            [11] => avg
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [9] => sum
            [10] => sum
            [11] => avg
        )

)
```

What I am trying to get is an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [9] => sum
                            [10] => sum
                            [11] => avg
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I this example only shows 3 levels deep but I need this to be dynamic as there will be different grouping options available. Some will only be 1 level which is easy but then there will be 2 or more also. The nested levels should always have the same keys as the parent levels.

What I am doing is using this to iterate over the data. The keys are the indexes in the array of the data I am grouping. The issue is, I need the lower levels of grouping to be aware of the other indexes as this is necessary for proper grouping of multiple datasets. This is to try to simplify processing large datasets. I only need to calculate the lowest level (in this example 9) so I can go over the final array to calculate the grouped data for each parent grouping. I'll use key 9 data to build key 4 data and key 4 data to build key 0 data. The reason the keys need to be aware of the parents is that the data is unique to the parent group. $a[0][4][9] is not the same as $a[0], $a[4], $a[9]. I need 9 to know it's dependent on 4 and 4 is dependent on 0.

I'm not sure if PHP can do this or if this even makes sense. Can you dynamically build an array like that?

Comment: Why did you get the above array and why you need to change into the next array? Will the key varies other value?

Comment: Are we required to check that the sub arrays are identical? Do the trees get more complex than the one you have shown?

Comment: @RyanVincent if they are not identical you can't have the output that the OP want

Comment: They are expected to be identical, basically, the parent groups will sum or average the data of each child group. While the lowest child is the only one processing all the data. The original array is the parameters passed by the grouping options that the user selects. I need to take that array and build the desired array above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another recursive 'tree', except it is 'one-way' rather than 'multi-way'. i.e. it is a 'linked list'. The 'node data' is only stored in the final node as it is identical in each node.

As usual: [Working code at Codepad.org](http://codepad.org/1gwWQZAM)

I found it quite 'interesting' to work out what i should 'initialize' the output with and what to 'recurse' with. Anyway here is the code...

I decided to simplify the code by dealing with some 'special cases' explicitly at the start...

```
if (count($source) <= 0) {
    return array();
}
elseif (count($source) == 1) {
    return array(key($source) => current($source));
}
```

Next, the function that does the work...

```
/**
 * Add all nodes to the 'tree'
 *
 * @param type $outNode -- a 'reference' to the current node to be added to
 * @param type $curKey  -- the index of the current node -- need this when overwriting the 'null' value later.
 * @param type $source  -- a reference to the source array as i do not want a copies to be made
 *
 * @return array -- current node
 */
function addNode(&$outNode, $curKey, &$source)
{
    // get the current node details...
    $curKey = key($source);
    $curItems = current($source);

    // advance to the next source node...
    next($source);

    // Is this the final node in the list?
    if (current($source) !== false) { // more nodes to add. We need to recurse...
        $nextKey = key($source);

        $outNode[$curKey] = array($nextKey => null);
        return addNode($outNode[$curKey], $nextKey, $source); // recurse
    }

    // add the items to the last node
    $outNode[$curKey] = $curItems;

    return $outNode;
}
```

The starting conditions and build the output...

```
// generated tree in here
$outTree = array();

// I use the key(), current() and next() functions as I use the 'internal' array iterator.
$curKey = key($source);
$curItems = current($source);

$outTree[$curKey]  = null; // the 'null' always gets overwritten later.

// build the tree...
$lastNode = addNode($outTree, $curKey,  $source);

// show the output...
echo '<pre>';
print_r($outTree);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

Output using the supplied data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [9] => sum
                            [10] => sum
                            [11] => avg
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks for your help. I have never seen this so I am playing with it a bit to better understand it. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

As you say that this will be dinamically, first you need to know the first index of your array, I call it `$last` because in the loop is the last used index:

```
$last = array_search(array_slice($array, 0, 1), $array);
```

then in `$temp` you go saving the array definition before and through the loop.

After the loop you need add the value of your deep array (in this case with `var_export`) and you need add all the finals `)` (in this case with `str_repeat`)

```
$temp .= var_export($array[$last], true) . str_repeat(')', $i);
```

and when you have the final string (array definition) just call `eval`

```
eval($temp . ';');
```

See the code:

```
<?php

$array = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            9 => 'sum',
            10 => 'sum',
            11 => 'avg'
        ),

    4 => Array
        (
            9 => 'sum',
            10 => 'sum',
            11 => 'avg'
        ),

    9 => Array
        (
            9 => 'sum',
            10 => 'sum',
            11 => 'avg'
        )
);

$last = array_search(array_slice($array, 0, 1), $array);
$temp = "\$newArray = ";
$i = 0;

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  $temp .= "array({$key} => ";
  $last = $key;
  $i++;
}

$temp .= var_export($array[$last], true) . str_repeat(')', $i);

eval($temp . ';');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [9] => sum
                            [10] => sum
                            [11] => avg
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: @Jeremy you got some advance?

Comment: I will be testing this tonight. Thanks for your feedback. I'm not sure if I want to use eval but if that's my only option, so be it.